# Add new values on button click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am working on Angular 9 where I am stuck at point where my code is working as per my expectations but testcases somehow are not executing.
Here is my github link for complete  code https://github.com/mehulk05/RestuarentAdd

The problem is when I add any value in input feild and click on submit as per test case my data should be added when I click on submit button and should apppear in view so ,my data is appearing in view but somehow testcase is getting failed.Below is my code snippet

Note:I cant modify anything written in test cases

**component.html**

```
<div class="layout-column align-items-center mt-50">
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="myFunction(f)">

       
            <input type="text" class="large" name="name" 
            placeholder="Restaurant Name" [(ngModel)]="name"
            data-test-id="restaurant-name-input" />

            <input type="text" class="large" name="city" 
            placeholder="City Name" [(ngModel)]="city" 
            data-test-id="city-name-input" />

            <button data-test-id="submit-button" 
            [disabled]="!city || !name">Submit</button>
    
    </form>
    <div class="card w-30 mt-30 pb-8">
        <table class="mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Restaurant name</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-test-id="restaurant-list">
                <tr *ngFor="let i of data">
                    <th>{{i.name}}</th>
                    <th>{{i.city}}</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class RestaurantDirectory implements OnInit {
  data: any[] = []
  name: string
  city: string
  
  ngOnInit() {
   
  }

  myFunction(f) {
    console.log(f.value)
    this.data.push(f.value)
    this.data = this.data.slice()
    console.log(this.data)
    f.reset()
  }
}
```

**Test.spec.ts**

```
describe('RestaurantDirectory', () => {
  let component: RestaurantDirectory;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RestaurantDirectory>;
  let restaurantNameInput;
  let cityNameInput;
  let submitBtn;
  let compiled;

  const pushValue = async (value1, value2) => {
    restaurantNameInput.value = value1;
    restaurantNameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    restaurantNameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    cityNameInput.value = value2;
    cityNameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    cityNameInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    submitBtn.click();
    await fixture.whenStable();
  };

  const getByTestId = (testId: string) => {
    return compiled.querySelector(`[data-test-id="${testId}"]`);
  };


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RestaurantDirectory);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    restaurantNameInput = getByTestId('restaurant-name-input');
    cityNameInput = getByTestId('city-name-input');
    submitBtn = getByTestId('submit-button');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

 it('Should add new values on btn click', async () => {
    const values1 = ['Hard Rock Cafe', 'Subway', 'McDonalds'];
    const values2 = ['San Jose', 'Seattle', 'New York'];
    await pushValue(values1[0], values2[0]);
    await pushValue(values1[1], values2[1]);
    await pushValue(values1[2], values2[2]);
    await fixture.autoDetectChanges(true);

    const restaurantList = getByTestId('restaurant-list');
    console.log(restaurantList)
    expect(restaurantList.children.length).toEqual(3);
    expect(restaurantList.children[0].children[0].innerHTML).toEqual('Hard Rock Cafe');
    expect(restaurantList.children[0].children[1].innerHTML).toEqual('San Jose');
    expect(restaurantList.children[1].children[0].innerHTML).toEqual('Subway');
    expect(restaurantList.children[1].children[1].innerHTML).toEqual('Seattle');
    expect(restaurantList.children[2].children[0].innerHTML).toEqual('McDonalds');
    expect(restaurantList.children[2].children[1].innerHTML).toEqual('New York');
  });
```

Also when I console log in my test file it is showing empty html structure inside table

So I am getting error is **× Should add new values on btn click** when I run my test case.I am not sure what I am missing.I have also tried without template driven form approach.Any help will be helpful

Comment: I would try `await fixture.whenStable();`

Comment: @IAfanasov I cant change my test case.All i have to do is need to do changes in code